# Cron file in cron.d isn't running at all, why?

Tags: cron, crontab, cronjob

I am unable to run my cron file stored at

> /etc/cron.d

but it wouldn't run for unknown reasons :/ can someone please help?

Content of my cron file is as follows:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MAILTO=""

# test
*/1 * * * * php echo "Hello World" > /tmp/backup-test2.log 2>&1
```

I am using CentOS if that can help

**Troubleshooting I did**

Service is running which is checked by running `service crond status` command

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if the cron daemon is running (either using `service` or `ps axf | grep cron` to check it). Also I would use `crontab -e` to edit the crontab file, instead of accessing it directly in `/etc/cron.d`. A look in the syslog may also provide some insights in what is going wrong.